# How to decrease code redundancy while creating a new page in HTML

Tags: html

I was wondering what would be the best way to create a new page in HTML or Web? For instance, I have navigation: Home, contacts etc. I would prefer not to create every separate `contacts.html` file for different menu selection as I feel that copying same code to other `.html` is storage wasted. So, How can I avoid copying same repeating code while creating HTML/Web Pages.

And also is there a way in `HTML` to make ending of `urls` with `.html` to go off? What I mean is instead of `http://www.example.com/contacts.html` make it `http://www.example.com/contacts`

Comment: You are probally looking for a php framework like drupal. https://www.drupal.org/ good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `php` for different repeating section of your pages, like create separate `php` pages for `nav`, `footer`, or `contact` and use it multiple times or where you need by using `php` `include` statement like

```
<?php include('nav.php');?> //to include nav section
```

And for your second question, YES, there is a way to that, With .htaccess under apache you can do the redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

As for removing of .html from the url, you can use

```
http://www.example.com/page
```

for

```
http://www.example.com/page.html
```